# Bash syntax error when specifying start time for SLURM

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting, and am trying to execute the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i j=0
for i in {4..10..2}
do
        rm -f experiment.sh
        mkdir -p /$WRKDIR/output$i
        echo "time $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop distcp file://$WRKDIR/random.file file://$WRKDIR/output$i" > experiment.sh
        sbatch --begin=now+(4*j)hour -N $i hadoopslurm.sh test$i
        ((j++))
done
```

When doing so, I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid time specification (pos=3): now+(4*j)hour
sbatch: error: Invalid time specification now+(4*j)hour
Invalid time specification (pos=3): now+(4*j)hour
sbatch: error: Invalid time specification now+(4*j)hour
Invalid time specification (pos=3): now+(4*j)hour
sbatch: error: Invalid time specification now+(4*j)hour
Invalid time specification (pos=3): now+(4*j)hour
sbatch: error: Invalid time specification now+(4*j)hour
```

I cannot figure out the correct syntax. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Maybe you need to prefix the references to j with a $ sign.. i.e. ((${j}++)) and (4*${j}) ... I always enclose my shell vars with {} - comes in very useful when you're concatenating stuff together.

Comment: You should first follow an introducing tutorial about shell scripting, then ask here about what is still unclear. Too many errors are in your script, no chance to answer without correcting the whole script. (I tried it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `j` is not properly resolved and hence is treated as a literal character.
You should prefix it with `$` like `$j` to indicate it is a variable.
Your increment statement `((j++))` probably also won't work. Try instead:

```
sbatch --begin=now+(4*$j)hour -N $i hadoopslurm.sh test$i
j=$((j+1))
```